# Error installing openjdk-7-jre on Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

On install I get this:

```
Unpacking openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 (7u51-2.4.6-1ubuntu4) ...
```

Finally followed by this:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates-java
 openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64
 openjdk-7-jre:amd64
 icedtea-7-jre-jamvm:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried:

```
apt-get autoclean
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
```

To no avail. I've purged every package it complains about. I've removed the packages from `/var/lib/dpkg/info` manually. No idea how to proceed!

Comment: Is there any useful information in /var/log/apt/term.log or /var/log/apt/history.log?

Comment: @sisyphus here's a gist of my history.log: https://gist.github.com/conbrad/26472436b2f73f691d2f

It doesn't look useful to me but maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 && \
(echo "deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list) && \
apt-get update -y && \
apt-get install -t jessie-backports openjdk-7-jdk -y
```

Answer (score -1):

While setting up Java on my chromebook, I found this site that made my life a TON easier. Here is the link [DigitalOcean Java for Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get) with relevant part below.

To install OpenJDK 7, execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

This will install the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). If you instead need the Java Development Kit (JDK), execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

I've never had any issues over the many installs that I've ended up having to do after countless powerwashes for my chromebooks.

I hope this helps out.

Comment: @DavidR any jdk/jre I try to install runs into the same dependency errors, starting with ca-certificates-java. No matter if it is default-jdk, openjdk-7-jre, openjdk-7-jdk...